# How to scale RabbitMQ across multiple Kubernetes Clusters

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, azure-aks

I have an application running in a Kubernetes cluster Azure AKS which is made up of a website running in one deployment, background worker processes running as scheduled tasks in Kubernetes, RabbitMQ running as another deployment and a SQL Azure DB which is not part of the Kubernetes.

I would like to deploy achieve load balancing and failover by deploying another kubernetes cluster in another region and placing a Traffic Manager DNS Load Balancer in front of the web site.

The problem that I see is that if the two rabbit instances are in separate kubernetes clusters then items queued in one will not be available in the other.

Is there a way to cluster the rabbitmq instances running in each kubernetes cluster or something besides clustering?
Or is there a common design pattern that might avoid problems from having seperate queues?

I should also note that currently there is only one node running RabbitMq in the current kuberntes cluster but as part of this upgrade it seems like a good idea to run multiple nodes in each cluster which I think the current Helm charts support.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't cluster RabbitMQ nodes across regions. Your cluster will get split brain because of network delays. To synchronise RabbitMQ queues, exchanges between clusters you can use federation or shovel plugin, depending on your use case.

Federation plugin can be enabled on a cluster by running commands:

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_federation
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_federation_management
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Mode details on [Federation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html).

For shovel:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel_management
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Mode details on [Shovel](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html).

Full example on how to setup Federation on RabbitMQ cluster can be found [here](https://codespacelab.com/rabbitmq-multi-region-setup/).

Comment: I wanted to acknowledge Marius answer. This looks very promising. I haven't marked it correct b/c I haven't had time to go through the Federation example yet but this might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Let me know if you will have any further questions :)

Comment: are you familiar with Kubernetes or Azure AKS? Any tips on implementing Federation in an environment like that?

Comment: It shouldn't be much difference in setup on k8s. Just when you will be setting up upstream ```rabbitmqctl set_parameter federation-upstream my-upstream \
'{"uri":"amqp://admin:guest@cluster1_rabbitmq-01_1:5672","expires":3600000}' ``` you will need to find out how to point it to *cluster1_rabbitmq-01_1* maybe it can be find by service name, depends on your setup.

Comment: read some of the Federation documentation. It seems that Federation causes a message sent to one queue to also be sent to the other queues federated to it. But if  a message is dequeued from one queue, it isn't also removed from the Federated queue. Is that a correct understanding?

If each message represented a piece of work to be done, is there a pattern to prevent the same message dequeued in different Federated queued from causing duplicate work from being performed.

Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes and as I understood thats what you want to achieve? Data synchronisation between your k8s clusters? If you don't want events to be synchronised by federated queues, what are you trying to achieve by making clusters talk to each other? Since if you are looking for better performance you need to scale your services in a cluster and not RabbitMQ. What is the business case you are trying to solve?

Comment: Side comment on @zack questions about AKS - I can highly recommend Azure AKS as a stable k8s service for all your stateless container workloads on Azure. I do not recommend to run something like RabbitMQ (cluster) in AKS or k8s vanilla for that matter. The level (and cost) of configuration you would need to be able to handle pods being torn down or arbitrary restarts in any order - without manual intervention - is simply to great to against having a "bare" Iaas setup.
PM if you are interested to hear more from our experiences.